# Overriding a method with stricter generic

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, d3.js

Using d3.js in typescript I'm trying to override a method that that returns a SVGElement selection with a method that returns a more specific SVGRectElement selection.

```
class ElementSelector {
    public getSelection(): d3.Selection<SVGElement, any, any, any> {
        return d3.select<SVGElement, any>("");
    }
}

class RectSelector extends ElementSelector {
    public getSelection(): d3.Selection<SVGRectElement, any, any, any> {
        return d3.select<SVGRectElement, any>("");
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Class 'B' incorrectly extends base class 'A'.
  Types of property 'getSelection' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Selection<SVGRectElement, any, any, any>' is not assignable to type '() => Selection<SVGElement, any, any, any>'.
      Type 'Selection<SVGRectElement, any, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Selection<SVGElement, any, any, any>'.
        Types of property 'datum' are incompatible.
          Type '{ (): any; (value: null): Selection<SVGRectElement, undefined, any, any>; <NewDatum>(value: Value...' is not assignable to type '{ (): any; (value: null): Selection<SVGElement, undefined, any, any>; <NewDatum>(value: ValueFn<S...'.
            Type 'Selection<SVGRectElement, undefined, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Selection<SVGElement, undefined, any, any>'.
              Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
                Type '{ (typenames: string): ValueFn<SVGRectElement, undefined, void> | undefined; (typenames: string, ...' is not assignable to type '{ (typenames: string): ValueFn<SVGElement, undefined, void> | undefined; (typenames: string, list...'.
                  Type 'ValueFn<SVGRectElement, undefined, void> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValueFn<SVGElement, undefined, void> | undefined'.
                    Type 'ValueFn<SVGRectElement, undefined, void>' is not assignable to type 'ValueFn<SVGElement, undefined, void> | undefined'.
                      Type 'ValueFn<SVGRectElement, undefined, void>' is not assignable to type 'ValueFn<SVGElement, undefined, void>'.
                        The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                          Type 'SVGElement' is not assignable to type 'SVGRectElement'.
```

Apparently I cannot assign SVGRectElement to SVGElement but the reason is not clear to me.

For example, this works:

```
interface Gen<T> { 
  prop: T
}

class A {
    init(param1: number): Gen<SVGElement> {
      return { prop: {} as SVGElement };
    }
}

class B extends A {
    init(param1: number): Gen<SVGRectElement> {
        return { prop: {} as SVGRectElement  };
    }
}
```

What am I missing?